Number of possible circles with at least two people
I was given this question:

In how many possible ways can we arrange $n$ people in circles such that the order between the circles does not matter, but the order with in each circle does matter, and we have at least $2$ people in each circle.
The answer should be a recursive formula.

Here is my try:

Say we know $\operatorname{f}\left(n - 1\right)$ , well if we want to add another person to the arrangement, we just need to decide who would be on his right.
There are $n - 1$ people in already arranged, so there are $n - 1$ possibilities for the one outside to choose from.
So it made sense to me that the answer would be
$$
\operatorname{f}\left(n\right) =
\left(n - 1\right)\operatorname{f}\left(n - 1\right)
$$
which is just $(n-1)!$, but after trying it for the first couple of values I realized that this fails ( on $n = 4$ for example ).


Your reasoning looks fine, except for this: you are not counting the arrangements in which the new person forms a circle with another single person. Let's try to fix that:
$$f(n) = (n−1)f(n−1) + (n-1) f(n-2) = (n-1) \left[f(n-1)+f(n-2) \right]$$
where the last term counts all those missed arrangements: the $n-1$ factor counts all the possible persons which will be paired with the new one.
I get:
n  f(n)
2   1
3   2
4   9
5   44
6   265
7   1874

See https://oeis.org/A000166

one thing i dont quiet get, how come that this dosent compile with the base cases? for n=0 the answer is clearly 0, and it is so for n=1 (since we are not allowed to have 1 person circles). so by this recursion formula we suppose to get f(2) = (2-1)(f(0)+f(1)) = 0. yet the answer is clearly 1.

@JohannCarlFriedrichGauß The recursion can require that $n>2$ to get rid of ambiguous initial conditions. Anyway, it also works for $n=2$ if we consider that $f(1)=0$ (no valid configuration) but $f(0)=1$ (there is one and only one way to place zero persons in zero circles! , the same as there are $0!=1$ ways of permute $0$ objects) . This interpretation also agrees with the full https://oeis.org/A000166
